# Finding/highlighting significant elevation change

Tags: qgis, lidar, elevation

I am quite new to QGIS, so pardon if I use the wrong terminology etc.

I am scouting terrain to find new bouldering/climbing locations. My goal is to find significant elevation differences and highlight them. The idea is, that if there is a difference of 2+ meters in a very short distance, it would mean that there is something to climb there.

I have access to all kinds of data provided by Maanmittauslaitos, including elevation model, hill shade and LiDAR data. How can I process this data into something that would highlight or filter significant changes in elevation in a short distance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change rate of elevation is called slope. I think you are trying to calculate the slope of a terrain. You will need a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) to determine the slope. If you specify the distance e.g. 1 meter, your threshold slope will be arctan(2/1). You can calculate slope using the [*Slope*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/terrain_analysis.html#moderate-fa-calculating-the-slope) tool in QGIS. The output of slope is in degree.

After calculating slope, you can use the [*Raster Calculator*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator) to select the areas having slope > arctan(2) i.e. in degree, slope > 63. The output will be in binary, where 1 is the true condition.